# how to get only similar word with like mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I make an autocomplete search and I want to get words suggestions from the descriptions. For example I have a post description: "this is sample description".

I use this query

```
$sql ="SELECT post_content FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE LOWER(post_content) LIKE LOWER('%".$s."%') AND post_status='publish'";
```

but I get all the matching description. How can i get only one word that matches query? For example if I write "sam..." I want to get only "sample" word, or if i write "sample des..." I want to get "sample description" not the full description where that word is it.

Comment: in short you cant do that with mysql alone

Comment: I think so too. can you suggest me something?

Comment: once you have `post_content` use php regular expresion to match and extract the text required

Comment: reg. exp. too difficult for me. could you give an example please? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this if it works for you:

**sample**

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        SUBSTRING('this is sample description and more' FROM LOCATE('sample des','this is sample description and more'))
        ,' '
        ,LENGTH('sample des') - LENGTH(replace('sample des', ' ', '')) +1
    ) as result;
```

**result**

```
result
sample description
```

try this query for your sql:

```
$sql ="
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        SUBSTRING(post_content FROM LOCATE('".$s."',post_content))
        ,' '
        ,LENGTH('".$s."') - LENGTH(replace('".$s."', ' ', '')) +1
    )
 FROM {$wpdb->posts} 
 WHERE LOWER(post_content) LIKE LOWER('%".$s."%') AND post_status='publish'";
```

please let me know if it works for you (its not testet)

Comment: omg, thank you sooo much!!!! I am very very grateful to you, it works :)

Comment: @user3514052 - ok, there is only a little known bug. If they any more spaces between two words in the search string the result will give you a word more, but you can replace 2 scpaces into one in PHP or change every $s to **replace('".$s."', '  ', ' ')** in the SQL